# API + WebApp when using php mvc pattern

Tags: php, api, model-view-controller

I have a web app that's written in `PHP` using the `MVC` pattern(some consider it MVP but I like the controller - presenter? - being in charge of my views). Now I want to develop an `API` and integrate it into my existing app. But since the api doesn't have a view I have a problem: do I create a totally different router and a new base controller for SoC purposes? But I need to use some models in the API and some libs and going for another router/base controller would mean basically creating another app altogether.

For now, I'm just using the second function in the base controller:

```
// base controller

//call a model
public function model($model, $data = null){

    $model_file = $model;
    $model = ucfirst(strtolower($model)) . 'Model';

    require_once '..' . DS . 'models' . DS . $model_file . '.php';

    return new $model($data);

}

//call this from controllers that have views 
public function view($view){
    require_once '..' . DS . 'views' . DS . $view . '.php';
}

//call this from the api controller
public function api(){

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    exit(json_encode($this->_data));

}
```

And then i'm using those function something like this:

```
//classic controller
class HomeController extends Controller{

    public static function index(){
       $user = $this->model('user');
        //some logic here
       $this->view('home');
    } 

}

//api controller
class APIController extends Controller{

    public static function v1{
        $user = $this->model('user');
        //some logic here
        $this->_data = ['api' => ['version'=> '1.0']]; //some random array
        $this->api();

    }        

}
```

Answer (score -1):

> going for another router/base controller would mean basically creating another app altogether.

True, but most people that want an API, just want to give people controlled access to their database. If that is what you want then you can use an 'automatic API' from [this list](https://github.com/dbohdan/automatic-api). This way you don't have to do much coding (only configure the security) and get an full-featured consistent API.

Comment: So basically i should separate my api from my app base controller? If yes can you provide any resources that explain this stuff in more details? Thank you!

Comment: You can take a look at my project ([PHP-CRUD-API](https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api)) and see how easy it is to get a full featured API with minimal programming. I'm happy to answer any questions you have via Github issues.

Comment: That's way too complex for me/my needs atm. Is there any small basic api that follows a pattern that could help me start small?